# How to upgrade the version of Python used by Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, python, path, paths

On a Red Hat box, I upgraded Python from 2.3 to 2.6.4 and changed the symlink to `python` so when I type in `python` the 2.6.4 interpreter comes up.

However my .py file works from the command-line, but not in the browser. It seemed like a `sys.path` issue so I opened the file in a browser and printed out `sys.path`.

Surprisingly, my `sys.path` is different when called from a browser than when called from a command-line. Because the paths are all referring to 2.3, I believe Apache is picking up Python 2.3 rather than the new 2.6.4 version I installed.

How do I make Apache use Python 2.6.4 rather than 2.3? Both are installed.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to need to recompile `mod_python`.  The better solution is to not use mod_python at all.  Instead, run your Python applications as FastCGI which will provide you with a much more flexible platform in the long term.

Comment: Wow. This is not my server. Any way to do this without rebuilding Apache?

Comment: Use some other method of serving your Python code (i.e. FastCGI)

Comment: I haven't installed FastCGI before - but http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/?q=node/9 (apparently the official docs?) say I need to install mod_fastcgi? How do I find if it is installed?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to install the python2.6 and mod_python 2.6 packages from [iuscommunity repository](http://iuscommunity.org) . They are very stable and reliable.

Comment: You're assuming that he's using a RedHat based distribution

Comment: I am using RedHat, I did mention in the question. Thank you all, I will go and Google both mod_python and mod_fastcgi later. Right now I solved my original issue by re-installing modules I needed, on Python 2.3.